# Using a speed rope?

Tags: upper-body-workout, stamina, jump-rope

So I found a speed rope, those really light jump ropes in my garage, and I need to exercise, so I took it in my house. I went on YouTube, but it seemed there were only tutorials using a heavy rope and I'm not willing to spend money cause I'm cheap, and I want to use the jump rope for something, so how can I reach the same results from a speed rope. My goal right now is to improve stamina, since I get tired after less than a third of a mile, and also build upper body strength.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A speed rope is good for working on conditioning , a weighted rope would be what you use to gain upper body strength. Since  you say  you are cheap and don't want to go out and buy another rope.  I would advise you to find something you hold in your hands that has a little weight to it. That something would have to allow you to hold the speed rope at the same time.  A weighted rope does not weigh that much  and it does everything else a speed rope does. Great cardio ,helps your agility and it does help you strengthen your upper-body.You can also find some 3 pound dumbbells  and simulate jumping rope with the dumbbells in your hands.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing a 21-15-9 complex with the rope and something else to build up general fitness. A good workout would be for time.

21 double unders (or 60 single unders), followed by 21 burpees
15 double unders (or 45 single unders), followed by 15 burpees
9 double unders (or 20 single unders), followed by 9 burpees

If you can do this in around 8 min you can add another exercise.

Both skipping and burpees tend to help with general fitness. They're also reasonably safe and don't require much equipment.